# ヤフー知恵袋のようなQ&Aサイトを作りたい

Tags: php, database

ヤフー知恵袋のようなQ&Aサイトでは、質問ごとにユニークなURLが与えられていると思うのですが、
データベースから受け取り表示させると同時にユニークなURLを与えることは可能でしょうか？
可能でしたら、大まかで良いので方法を教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 今の書き方だと「何が分からないのか」が分かりづらい印象です。ポイントは "ユニークなURLを与える" 部分でしょうか？

Comment: タイトルが「QAサイトを作りたい」と書いていますが、それがこの質問の主題ではないと思います。適切なタイトルをつけるとより目が引きやすく回答が得られると思います。

Comment: もし途中まででも作成したソースコードがあるのであれば、それを開示していただくと、質問者さんの意図にそった方向で解決することのできる回答が得られるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

URLを与えるというより、
「仮想のURLでアクセスしたときに、そのURLに含まれる値を用いてDBから情報を取得して表示」
している、という考え方です。WebサーバのURLリライトという機能です。

http://example.com/hoge1/hoge2
でアクセスすると、
http://example.com/index.php?id=hoge1&name=hoge2
みたいに書き換えて内部処理するわけです。（どう書き換えるかは設定次第）

通常は設定を細かく書く必要がありますが、
（Apacheであれば.htaccess、Nginxであればnginx.conf、IISであればweb.config）
LaravelやCakePHPをはじめとるする主要なPHPフレームワークには、
かんたんにこれを実現できるルーティング機能が搭載されています。